# hash map with arraylist and create new arraylist out of it

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to clean my code and want to used optimised approches in the code.

Currently I have hashmap of this type
 `private HashMap<String, ArrayList<allProperty>> fData;`

So The data is coming from server in every 5 second. and I am updating this hashmap every 5 second something like this

```
       fData.put("Student", allStudent);
       fData.put("Emp", allEmp);
       fData.put("Other", allOther);
```

So from allproperty class object, there is marks fields and I am trying to extract that marks field for all key and creating new arraylist of integer so that I can append the marks in created arraylist by every 5 second.

I was using different arraylist for each student, emp and other before and it was working fine but it seems like alot of repeation of code. That is why I am trying to achieve it with hash map

I am trying soemthing like this but it is not appending data ...

```
for (String type: allTypes) {
            if(fData.get(type).size() > 0){
                arraySort(fData.get(type));
                temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                temp.add(fData.get(type).get(0).marks);
            }
            cData.put(type, temp);
```

cType is hashMap of type given below and

```
 private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> cData;
```

where allTypes is

```
 signalTypes.add("Student");
    signalTypes.add("Emp");
    signalTypes.add("Other");
```

at the end I want three new arraylist with key and able to append data in every 5 seconds. Thanks

Comment: the class allProperty should have marks as public field...

Comment: yes it has...I can access it ..that i know

Comment: Are you sure it would not be better using 'addAll' for temp? It is not clear what the type of `fData` and `marks`.

Comment: try print this in log fData.get(type).get(0).marks does it get data correctly? it should give int.. as temp is ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: yes it gets but the problem is when I get new data after 5 second, it does not append in new created arraylist ..I hope I am clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get your `ArrayList`

2a. If it doesn't exist - put your `new ArrayList`

2b. Else USE this `ArrayList`. It's mutable. So you can call `.add` on this object and it will be updated in `HashMap`

Try this:

```
for (String type: allTypes) {
        if (fData.get(type).size() > 0) {
            arraySort(fData.get(type));
            if (cData.get(type) == null) {
                temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                temp.add(fData.get(type).get(0).marks);
                cData.put(type, temp);
            } else {
                cData.get(type).add(fData.get(type).get(0).marks);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: but I guess I am doing the same ...the idea is to update each arrraylist specific to key

Comment: You creating `new ArrayList` instead of using old one in your code. When you use old one you shouldn't call map.put()

Comment: but if I would not create new one, then the loop will run for three times and add three values instead one for particular key

Comment: this is the error...as there is not object exist Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: put `== null` instead of `!= null`